# Routing from a single file

Tags: php, architecture, routes

```
domain.com
|
----> routes.php
|
----> dir
    |
    ----> home.php
    |
    ----> feed.php
    |
    ----> chats.php
```

Now If somebody hits `domain.com` I want them to route to `domain.com/dir/home.php` using `routes.php` but I don't want to show `domain.com/dir/home.php` in `URL` bar of the browser. I want to show `domain.com` in the `URL` bar. I know it can be simply configured.

But If somebody hits `domain.com/dir/feed.php` I don't want to show `domain.com/dir/feed.php` in the `URL` bar, I want to show `domain.com/feed.php`

How this can be done? How all routes can be controlled from the `routes.php` file situated in root directory?

I am not using any MVC framework.

Comment: You can use just a .htaccess file with rules and some pho code to load according pages to your rules ([using this tutorial for example](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049)) or a routing implementation along with .htaccess. See [AltoRouter](https://github.com/dannyvankooten/AltoRouter), [FastRoute](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute), or search for _php routing_ in google..

Comment: Thank You. I know about using htaccess. These router classes can be useful to me.